# Piwik not showing the images

Tags: php, rhel, matomo

I installed/configured Piwik on a **RHEL 7** server (using **Apache 2.4 and PHP 7.0**), but the images are not displayed.

The URL f.ex. of the logo is http://localhost/plugins/Morpheus/images/logo.svg or "http://.../plugins/Morpheus/images/logo.png". When I will open the url directly, I get this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at (mail) to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an  ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I would be thankful for any help.

Best regards

**"..plugins/.htaccess":**

```
'# This file is auto generated by Piwik, do not edit directly
# Please report any issue or improvement directly to the Piwik team.

# First, deny access to all files in this directory
<Files "*">
<IfModule mod_version.c>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from All
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
                Require all denied
        </IfVersion>
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_version.c>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from All
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                Require all denied
        </IfModule>
</IfModule>
</Files>
# Serve HTML files as text/html mime type - Note: requires mod_mime apache module!
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
   AddHandler text/html .html
   AddHandler text/html .htm
</IfModule>

# Allow to serve static files which are safe
<Files ~ "\.(gif|ico|jpg|png|svg|js|css|htm|html|swf|mp3|mp4|wav|ogg|avi|ttf|eot)$">
<IfModule mod_version.c>
        <IfVersion < 2.4>
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion >= 2.4>
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
                #Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_version.c>
        <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from All
                #Require all granted
        </IfModule>
</IfModule>
</Files>'
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in the php error log? Did you install it from the zip on the homepage or from github?

Comment: I installed it from the zip on the homepage. I have only error in apache log:  [core:alert] [pid 19946:tid 140541675198208] [client ip-address:62554] /appbase/http/piwiktest/plugins/.htaccess: <IfModule not allowed here, referer: 'http://localhost/

Comment: Is it possible you have disabled the use of .htaccess files?
https://serverfault.com/a/529015

Comment: I have commented all the lines in "../piwik/plugins/.htaccess" and "../piwik/libs/.htaccess" (see above for the file content).  This solved my problem. At least the pages/images were displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have commented all the lines in "../piwik/plugins/.htaccess" and "../piwik/libs/.htaccess" (see above for the file content). This solved my problem. At least the pages/images were displayed correctly.